# DDL VS DCL difference

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle site
[Types of SQL Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_1001.htm#SQLRF30001)
Grant and Revoke belongs to DDL but in lot of other sites I see Grant and Revoke in DCL... which one is correct?

Comment: These are definitions, and by their nature they can't be "correct" or "incorrect." Rather, what you need to say is that "using the DDL definition used in the Oracle documentation, GRANT statements are DDL statements." In most (but not all) cases you are best off following Oracle's definition unless you have a strong reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

It is best to treat `GRANT` and `REVOKE` as DDL.

As mathguy pointed out, neither definition is truly "correct".  But I recommend you stick with the Oracle definition for two reasons:

1. **Oracle has thoroughly classified almost everything.**  Every possible Oracle SQL command from `V$SQLCOMMAND` will fit in their system.  The only exceptions I've found are PL/SQL (an anonymous PL/SQL block), Invalid (a command that doesn't make sense), and Nothing (an empty string).  One could argue that those aren't really SQL statements, although in some contexts it's still useful to classify them.  I've found the Oracle classification system helpful for creating some PL/SQL language tools.
2. **The classification occasionally matters.**  For example, it's important to know exactly what Oracle considers to be DDL when calling `DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT`.  Anything other than a true DDL will silently fail.